# How can I provide an editable default value when prompting for user input?

Tags: perl, terminal, prompt

In a Perl script, I want to prompt the user for input and offer him an *editable* default value. So far I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "what's your name? [John Doe]: ";
$name = <STDIN>;
chomp $name;
if (!$name)
{
    $name = "John Doe";
}
print "hello $name.\n";
```

What I'm looking for is a solution where I can have "John Doe" on `STDIN` already before the user starts typing. So it's practically an editable default input. E.g. the user could press backspace 3x and then type "Wayne" to get "John Wayne" rather than typing the whole string "John Wayne" from beginning on. I tried to print to `STDIN`, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You by definition cannot write to stdin.  You’re going to have to use something like [`Term::ReadLine::Gnu`](http://p3rl.org/Term%3a%3aReadLine%3a%3aGnu).

The feature you are looking for is called `PREPUT`, it is the second argument to the `readline` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Try this. It worked for me on Windows 10, Perl 5.32
use Term::ReadLine;  # Do not "use Term::ReadLine::Gnu;"
my $term ;
my $prompt = "Enter a name: " ;
my $name   = "John Doe" ;
$term = Term::ReadLine->new('Test script', \*STDIN, \*STDOUT);  
$name = $term->readline($prompt,$name) ; 
print "\nThe name is $name" ;
```