# How can I provide an editable default value while reading STDIN with Java?

Tags: java, io, console

. . I have a Java console app that is displaying a list of key=value properties to the user and indexes them so that they can type an index number, then edit the value, e.g.:

```
[0] foo=value 1
[1] bar=value 2
prompt> edit 1
bar=value 2
new value?: *
```

(Asterisk is the prompt).  I'm collecting the input using what I think is the standard idiom for that:

```
BufferedReader bufferRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        input = bufferRead.readLine();
```

My problem is that I want to provide the existing value to the user after the prompt so that they can simple modify the value, e.g.:

```
[0] foo=value 1
[1] bar=value 2
prompt> edit 1
bar=value 2
new value?: value 2*
```

How would I go about doing that?  It seems conceptually I would want to pre-load the input reader with the existing value but I'm not sure if that's the right thought or how I'd do that.  I saw a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021871/how-can-i-provide-an-editable-default-value-when-prompting-for-user-input) for perl but didn't run across anything for Java.  I have a feeling this is something that seems easy but isn't. . . ?

Andy

Comment: Trying to get a better sense of the question. So you have an array of items. i.e. array["apple","bat","cow"]. The console pops up and when you enter "1", it would first show you the value of item 1, so in this case it would show you "bat", then the next thing you type would replace the value of "bat" aka (array[1]) on enter. Is this correct?